# Chained ZipInputStream (SharpZipLib) with CryptoStream will cause GetNextEntry() to fail after the last entry

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, zip

I have noticed a strange behaviour that I can't control.
Zip files are being encrypted like this:

```
private static void EncryptFile(string source, string destination, string password, int iteration)
    {
        var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 1000, iteration);

        using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged
        {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            KeySize = 128,
            BlockSize = 128
        })
        {
            aes.Key = keyGenerator.GetBytes(16);
            aes.IV = keyGenerator.GetBytes(16);

            using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(source))
            {
                using (var destinationStream = File.OpenWrite(destination))
                {
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(destinationStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        //salt (uncrypted)
                        destinationStream.Write(keyGenerator.Salt, 0, keyGenerator.Salt.Length);
                        //rest (crypted)
                        sourceStream.CopyTo(cs);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This method will decrypt and unzip the file on the fly.

```
private static void UnzipDecryptFile(string source, string destination, string password, int iteration)
    {
        using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged
                     {
                         Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                         Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
                         KeySize = 128,
                         BlockSize = 128
                     })
        {
            using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(source))
            {
                var salt = new byte[1000];
                sourceStream.Read(salt, 0, 1000);

                var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iteration);

                aes.Key = keyGenerator.GetBytes(16);
                aes.IV = keyGenerator.GetBytes(16);

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(sourceStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (var zipStream = new ZipInputStream(cs))
                    {
                        ZipEntry entry;

                        while ((entry = zipStream.GetNextEntry()) != null)
                        {
                            var c = entry.DateTime;
                            //do stuff with entry
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunaly I can't use [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(Stream stream)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) because it will copy the whole stream to **memory** if the stream doesn't support **CanSeek**, which CryptoStream doesn't.

At the very last call to zipStream.GetNextEntry() I get a CryptographicException: **Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.**

```
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Streams.InflaterInputStream.Close()
   at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.Close()
   at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.GetNextEntry()
```

[GetNextEntry() will cause close on stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4m9J.png)

This seems to be the correct behaviour. ZipInputstream.GetNextEntry() doesn't find a next entry, so it closes everything down.

For some reasons the CryptoStream.Dispose() method thinks it should call **FlushFinalBlock()** But since everything is already decrypted, it fails.

If I use **PaddingMode.Zeros** instead of **PadddingMode.PKCS7** it will work, but that's not really an option since this mode is not available in java (the side that will generate the zip files) by default.

What am I missing?

[EDIT]
Just to me more precise: The decrypting/unpacking works just fine. The error occurs during the disposing after the last call to **zipStream.GetNextEntry()**. And with some Zip files the error will not occur at all. This might be files with a size of a multitude of 16 (blocksize) that don't need padding.

Comment: Here is some useful info.  I've seen with MemoryStream class.  When you fill a memory stream the position is set to the end.  When you go to read the memory stream you have to first set position to zero before reading.  If you don't you get an error like : stream doesn't support CanSeek.  A memory stream has two modes : Expand and cannot expand.  If you set a size of the memory stream it defaults to cannot expand.  So normally I do not specify size.  With crypto streams the encryption and decryption methods must be the same.  If they are not you will get exceptions like what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunatly it doesn't apply here. I have edited the question to try to be more specific.

Comment: It does because of the padding issue.  This has nothing to do with the zip.  It has to do with using the same options to encrypt and decrypt.  The error is not necessarily caused by the padding.  When you do not use the same options for encrypting and decrypting the error that occurs is Padding.  The encryption modes have a 64 bit, 128 bit, and 256 bit mode.  If you use different modes for encrypt then decrypt the error that will occur is padding, but the root cause in the number of bits being used.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts, but I've lost you. As the code shows, the same Mode (CBC), Padding (PKCS7), Keysize (128) and Blocksize (128) are being used during encryption/decryption. Are you telling me that they are different?

Comment: You are only showing the c# and not the java.  So I can't tell which options java is using.  And there are other options that need to be set properly.  There are lots of postings for java and c# not working together and you can search the web for solutions.  I just used the size as an example.But other options can also cause padding exceptions.A few years ago I answered a posting and to get code to work I tried every combination of 5 different options before I got the correct combination.I put the code into a exception handler so when one combination gave a failure the code would try the next.

Comment: ok, I understand the confusion. I only mentioned java so that nobody would suggest to use **PaddingMode.Zeros** (which will do the trick, but does not exist on java). Right now, java is not involved in this repro. People can just take the first method to encrypt a Zip, and the second one to decrypt/unzip it in a specified folder. All C#, no java

Comment: You need to find out which modes java supports and then use equivalent mode in c#.  Plenty of discussion on this on web.  It is a very common issue that encryption is not the same between c# and java and the solution to issue.  I've read this posting but never answered them.

Comment: ZipInputStream is not a .NET class?

Comment: @JamesKPolk: it's not in the framework. It's a class from the [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) project.

Comment: I tried it with my zip file of length 8409 bytes and it worked normally without error. The Close() in the little snippet you provided seems to occur in some  special cases where (I think) SharpZipLib detects the logical end of the zip entries but there are still some bytes left in the zip file, perhaps metadata of some sort.

Comment: Hi, I've come across the same issue and I can't get my head around this. @JamesKPolk, have you somehow solved this issue to keep the padding mode the same? I work in C# so I can change the padding mode to zeros but I would like to stick to PKCS7. Thanks